# Preventing goBack with useNavigate hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Is there a way to prevent back navigation using react's `useNavigate` hook? 
 I'm currently using `navigate("/",{replace: true})` for the time being but would like to have a proper solution for it.

Comment: you use useContext in your app?

Comment: Well what you're using is the proper way. What is the issue?

Comment: The way I am using actually replaces the page on top of the stack, which means it can still go back to the previous pages that are present in the stack. I want to completely disable the back button so that it can't go back to any previous page.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to fight browser's own mechanism like History and navigation is to check `history.length`:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (global.history.length> 1) {
    window.open(window.location.href, "_blank");
  }
}, []);
```

Imo it's rather confusing. Also when user opens new tab, `history.length` becomes `1`. So code above will not bring *another* tab only if opened from bookmark/by clicking link with `target="_blank"`.